# Why do Thunderbird Lightning notifications come late?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

It seems that the Thunderbird integration to Ubuntu is taking some time, and I'm okay with that, I have workarounds for most things like keeping Thunderbird open in the notification area, but there is one thing: the Lightning notifications about events (not Ubuntu's native notifications, but rather Lightning's pop-up window notifications), which I set usually to one hour before the event starts, never appear on time. They do appear, but much later on, and when I see them it's usually after the event is finished. I checked if it's a timezone problem in Thunderbird or Ubuntu, but in both places the timezone is set correctly. Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem or are you still looking for help? It sounds rather like a bug, perhaps you could file a bug report? [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about this! In one of the updates it was fixed, and now I don't have the problem anymore. It's as good as solved. What should I do with this question now?

Comment: You can just add the answer yourself "solved by an update" and accept it :)]

Comment: I'm running Thunderbird 17 and I still have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by an update. It works fine now.